# Sorting excel cells containing checkboxes

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet with a couple of columns containing checkboxes(Developer>Insert>FormControl). The checkboxes are linked to the cell they lie upon. When I sort, the linked cells get sorted properly but the checkboxes themselves behave completely wrong. How do I fix this? [Original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIIND.png) and
[Sorted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F38Oc.png)